# Type 'Selection<SVGElement>' is not comparable to type 'Selection<SVGSVGElement>'

Tags: typescript, d3.js, svg

I'm fairly new to Typescript and generics and I'm struggling to resolve a compiler issue.  I get the title error when I run the below code (compiling a target GitHub project).

I've tried changing the type cast for the `d3.Selection` to `<SVGSVGElement` unsuccessfully.  I could change it to `<any>` or `<unknown>` but I feel that would be cheating and not learning a lesson here.

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';

type D3SVGSelection = d3.Selection<SVGElement, any, null, undefined>;
```

Within the constructor for the class, I set this.svg:

```
constructor(elm: HTMLDivElement) {
    private svg: D3SVGSelection;

    this.svg = (d3.select(elm).append('svg') as D3SVGSelection)
               .attr('viewBox', '-5 5 130 110')
               .attr('style', 'width: 95%; height: 70%; margin-left:5px');
```

I understand that the issue is with the type definition of D3SVGSelection, however, I'm not certain how to resolve it.  Suggestions on how to troubleshoot this type of issue myself in the future?

Comment: `I've tried changing the type cast for the d3.Selection to <SVGSVGElement unsuccessfully.`; what error did you get?  that should be the right declaration.  Try, `type D3SVGSelection = d3.Selection<SVGSVGElement, any, null, undefined>;` then `this.svg = d3.select(elm).append<SVGSVGElement>('svg')`;

Comment: Upon review, I have to withdraw my comment.  Changing it to `SVGSVGElement` did in-fact correct this particular issue.  I was confusing it with another compiler error related to missing types.